# python. matplotlib. plot values based on other column's values (parallel lines)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, group-by

lets say that i have following dataframe, and i want to time to x axis, and vls and id to y axis. but i want to group line ids, to see the separet line ids and their corresponding 'vls'. so far i used 'groupby'
'

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'vls': [ -22.0390625, -22.03515625, -27.0, -15.99609375, -10.984375, -12.9765625, -12.97265625, -19.9609375,-13.96484375, -19.95703125, -13.953125, -19.94921875, -21.9453125, -11.94140625, -21.9375, -21.93359375, -16.92578125, -13.921875, -12.91796875, -19.9140625, -10.91015625, -10.90625, -19.90234375, -10.8984375], 'id' : [1,2,3,4,5,4,5,5,5,4,3,3,4,4,4,2,1,5,5,3,5,2,5,5], 'time' : [51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74]})
g1 = df.groupby(["id"])
for i, data in g1:
    plt.plot(df.time, df.vls.values, label = i, linestyle=':', marker = 'o')
    plt.plot(df.time, df.id.values, linestyle=':', marker = 'o') 
plt.legend()
```

but my output is like this:

[image]

but i would like to get 5 separate lines for id(should be 5 parallel lines) and 5 lines for 'vls' which is not connected sequentually, but based in 'id'column.
something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are still using the original dataframe, while you did use group correctly. I think you intended the following:

```
from numpy import *
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'vls': [ -22.0390625, -22.03515625, -27.0, -15.99609375, -10.984375, -12.9765625, -12.97265625, -19.9609375,-13.96484375, -19.95703125, -13.953125, -19.94921875, -21.9453125, -11.94140625, -21.9375, -21.93359375, -16.92578125, -13.921875, -12.91796875, -19.9140625, -10.91015625, -10.90625, -19.90234375, -10.8984375], 'id' : [1,2,3,4,5,4,5,5,5,4,3,3,4,4,4,2,1,5,5,3,5,2,5,5], 'time' : [51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74]})
g1 = df.groupby(["id"])
fig, ax = subplots()
colors = cm.tab10(arange(len(set(df.id.values))+1))
for i, data in g1:
    ax.plot(data.time, data.vls.values, label = i, color = colors[i],linestyle=':', marker = 'o')
    ax.plot(data.time, data.id.values, linestyle=':', color = colors[i], marker = 'o') 
ax.legend()
```

edit: added color matching (not sure if that is intended)

[image]